# Group by won't work in my statement. WHY

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, sum

Practice question for final SQL exam. 
List the total number of collections(fines and fees) and the total amount owned by crime classification.

This is my code. Please tell me why its not working.

```
select classification, fine_amount+court_fee as "collections amount", fine_amount - amount_paid as "Amount owned"
from crime_charges join crimes using (crime_id)
group by classification;
```

**Error thrown:**

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 23
```

Comment: Try it without the quotation marks around the aliases (example: `fine_amount+court_fee as collections amount`).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT classification, SUM(fine_amount+court_fee) AS "collections amount", 
       SUM(fine_amount - amount_paid) AS "Amount owned"
FROM crime_charges 
INNER JOIN crimes USING (crime_id)
GROUP BY classification;
```

Answer (score 0):

you must put all of your columns in the select clause into the group by clause.

Comment: this is an oracle specific problem. he is not using MySQL

Comment: The OP tagged it as MySQL, not Oracle.

Comment: doesn't mean it is MySQL. Do you believe every tag you see? ORA-00979 is an ORAcle error

Comment: No need to be rude. My comment was directed at others who find this question. Given that the OP thinks it is mysql and tagged it that way, it's worth clarifying that your comment is directed at Oracle, which OP is actually using, not mysql.

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
select classification, fine_amount+court_fee as "collections amount", fine_amount - amount_paid as "Amount owned"
from crime_charges join crimes using (crime_id)
group by classification,fine_amount,court_fee,amount_paid;
```

Answer (score 0):

@shabeer, I appreciate your interest in your learning. But still, it is always wise to invest your time in theoretical learning. The question of yours is very fundamental.
 A select query which uses `group by` can contain only aggregate functions and the columns grouped by in the select clause.
 Just imagine, how the database know to select a single value of the `fine_amount` column, when u already grouped the dataa with `classification` column. It may be either a `max`, `min`, `sum`.. etc..
Not my advise, but I just feel, when you get down to know the basics, you will feel the difference. When you search internet for solutions, it may get as a habbit!

All the best!